# Notation for "big fiber product"?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

If `X, Y` are sets equipped with maps `X \to Z`, `Y \to Z`, then the usual notation for the fiber product of `X` and `Y` over `Z` is `X \times_Z Y`.  I have a whole bunch of sets `X_\alpha` equipped with maps `X_\alpha \to Z`.  Does anyone have a suggestion for how to denote (in TeX) the fiber product of all these sets over `Z`? I would like to use `\prod`, but the subscript that indicates the indices over which we're taking the product and the subscript that indicates that we're taking a fiber product over `Z` are getting in each other's way.

Here was my super-ugly attempt using `\prod`: [image]

Currently my solution is what Sigur suggests in the comments.

Comment: Could you show a mock-up of what you actually want? Drawing it out on paper is fine.

Comment: No, I don't have a good idea of how to denote this.  So there's really two parts to this question -- a) how to denote this and b) how to convert the answer to a) into TeX.  I know that this forum is supposed to be just about TeX, and a) is about math notation generally, but still I thought that this forum would be more appropriate than the math stackexchange.

Comment: You mentioned you want to use `\prod`. Can you at least show us what that looks like? Not everyone here is a mathematician by trade, and so describing it purely in words isn't very helpful. Part (a) of your question is borderline off-topic, I would argue.

Comment: Nice math notation question. I have never seen such one. Maybe `$\bigotimes\limits_{\alpha\in A}^Z X_\alpha$`.

Comment: @Troy I added a picture of `\prod` to the question.

Comment: @Sigur yes, I agree with you -- that's my working solution.

Comment: @NathanielBottman I know what `\prod` is. I meant show us how you used it for the fiber product. I assume you tried, since you also said "the subscript that indicates the indices ... are getting in each other's way".

Comment: @Troy ok, fixed it.

Comment: @NathanielBottman, I agree that your first solution is not good. You can use `\prod` in my sugestion instead of `\bigotimes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me `\prod` is the more natural symbol compared to `\bigotimes`. This is analogous to the Cartesian product of sets (`\times` for the binary operator and `\prod` for the indexed version). The indexing should take place below the operator and the subscript `Z` should remain on the right. I don't think there's a nice way to do this inline.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\fprod}{\sideset{}{_Z}\prod}

\begin{document}
\[
\fprod_{\alpha\in A}X_{\alpha}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note the choice to center the index not under the `\prod`, but under the `\prod` together with the subscript. This is because the subscript is really part of the operator. If you prefer to have the index just centered under the `\prod` you could use the simpler code `\sideset{}{_Z}\prod_{\alpha\in A}X_{\alpha}`, without the `\DeclareMathOperator*` command.

Lastly, if you plan to change the `Z`, it would be nice to have `\fprod` take `Z` as an argument. Unfortunately, `\DeclareMathOperator` does not take arguments. One workaround would be to use

```
\newcommand{\fprod}[1]{\mathop{\sideset{}{_{#1}}\prod}}
```

and then

```
\fprod{Z}_{\alpha\in A}X_{\alpha}
```

produces the desired output. I suspect though, that experts will warn against using `\mathop`.